# Tag always 0 from sender (UIButton)

Tags: swift, tags

When I'm passing the tag value of a UIProgressView, however, it always appears to be 0 when I retrieve it from the sender in a method.

**Pseudo Code**

```
var c : Int = 0
func randomFunction () {
   c++
   // some settup for UIButton and UIProgressView
   myProgressView.tag = c
   myButton.addTarget(self, action: "holding:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
}
func holding (sender:UIButton!) {
   print(sender.tag)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that sender is the button not myProgressView so the tag of the sender which is myButton is always zero.

If you want to get the tag of myProgressView change your code as below:

```
func holding (sender:UIButton!) {
   print(myProgressView.tag)
}
```